# How can i start this function from the button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have  this JavaScript code and piece of html code. My problem is, when I open my webpage, this code starting automatically. I try to put it between button tag with onclick event, but than, not working.

```js
function openContent(evt, Name) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(Name).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function go() {
    i = i < width ? i + step : 1;
    m.style.marginLeft = -i + 'px';
  }
  var i = 0,
    step = 3,
    space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
  var t = m.innerHTML; //text
  m.innerHTML = t + space;
  m.style.position = 'absolute';
  var width = (m.clientWidth + 1);
  m.style.position = '';
  m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
  m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    step = 0;
  }, true);
  m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    step = 3;
  }, true);
  var x = setInterval(go, 50);
}, true);
```

```html
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Nyolcadik')">Nyolcadik feladat</button>
<div class="tabcontent" id="Nyolcadik">
  <div id="marquee">
    Hello!
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is openContent function?

Comment: sorry,i forget.

Comment: Can you please format this ? Also, including a link to a jsfiddle or codepen would be helpful

Comment: @Pytth Why would you ask for a remote link instead of a stack snippet?

Comment: It starts automatically because of `var x = setInterval(go, 50);`

Comment: so,i just have to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing here is

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
   setInterval(go, 50);
   });
```

```js
function openContent(evt, Name) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(Name).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function go() {
    i = i < width ? i + step : 1;
    m.style.marginLeft = -i + 'px';
  }
  var i = 0,
    step = 3,
    space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
  var t = m.innerHTML; //text
  m.innerHTML = t + space;
  m.style.position = 'absolute';
  var width = (m.clientWidth + 1);
  m.style.position = '';
  m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
  m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    step = 0;
  }, true);
  m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    step = 3;
  }, true);
   document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
   setInterval(go, 50);
   });
}, true);
```

```html
<button class="tablinks" id ='btn' >Nyolcadik feladat</button>
<div class="tabcontent" id="Nyolcadik">
  <div id="marquee">
    Hello!
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Just wrap code in function and run it onClick

```js
function openContent(evt, Name) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(Name).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function runMyCode() {
  function go() {
    i = i < width ? i + step : 1;
    m.style.marginLeft = -i + 'px';
  }
  var i = 0,
    step = 3,
    space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
  var t = m.innerHTML; //text
  m.innerHTML = t + space;
  m.style.position = 'absolute';
  var width = (m.clientWidth + 1);
  m.style.position = '';
  m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
  m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    step = 0;
  }, true);
  m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    step = 3;
  }, true);
  var x = setInterval(go, 50);
}
```

```html
<button class="tablinks" onclick="runMyCode();openContent(event, 'Nyolcadik')">Nyolcadik feladat</button>
<div class="tabcontent" id="Nyolcadik">
  <div id="marquee">
    Hello!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately,when i open my webpage,this start automatically again.:/

Comment: if it works here, then this pice of code is ok, check everything else on your page. Start from deleting all rest code, apply this one, then add everything else step by step and check out where problem is

Answer (score 0):

//The page loads automatically because you added a event listener of "load" for the code to start running.
// So the code automatically starts running once the page is **loaded.

// So I have removed that in my solution and I have created another function called "myFunction that contains the whole of the code you wrote initially and also added an event listener of "click" to the button so that when it is click it calls the "myFunction function.

see code below, this solves the automated loading it.

```
let btn=document.querySelector(".tablinks");
  btn.addEventListener("click",myFunction)
function myFunction(){
        function go() {
          i = i < width ? i + step : 1;
          m.style.marginLeft = -i + 'px';
      }
      var i = 0,
          step = 3,
          space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
      var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
      var t = m.innerHTML; //text
      m.innerHTML = t + space;
      m.style.position = 'absolute';
      var width = (m.clientWidth + 1);
      m.style.position = '';
      m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
      m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
          step = 0;
      }, true);
      m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
          step = 3;
      }, true);
      var x = setInterval(go, 50);
  } true;
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure if i understand what you want exactly but this :

`window.addEventListener('load',() => {})`
means that the code will operate once the page if fully loaded if you want the code to operate only when you click the button then get all the code that inside the eventlistener and put it inside your openContent() function
the code will look something like this

```
function openContent(evt, Name) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(Name).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  function go() {
    i = i < width ? i + step : 1;
    m.style.marginLeft = -i + 'px';
  }
  var i = 0,
    step = 3,
    space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
  var t = m.innerHTML; //text
  m.innerHTML = t + space;
  m.style.position = 'absolute';
  var width = (m.clientWidth + 1);
  m.style.position = '';
  m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
  m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    step = 0;
  }, true);
  m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    step = 3;
  }, true);
  var x = setInterval(go, 50);
}
```